# COUNTIF isn't recognized as a formula

Tags: excel, sequence, countif

I'm trying to count the number of Sundays in any user given month/year.

The problem is that Excel doesn't recognize the formula and throws the message:

There's a problem with this formula.
Not trying to type a formula?
...

I'm trying to use sequence and countif to calculate this and it works fine if I separate this into two steps:

Cell B2: Mar-23 (user input month/year)

Cell C2: `=WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(B3,0)-EOMONTH(B3,-1),,B3))` #Output: array with the weekday of each day in March 2023

Cell D2: `=COUNTIF(C2#,1)` #Output: 4 (nº of Sundays in Mar-23)

The problem is when I try to combine everything in one step, like so:

Cell b2: Mar-23 (user input month/year)

Cell C2: `=COUNTIF(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(B3,0)-EOMONTH(B3,-1),,B3)),1)`

Is there a way to get around this?
Thanks guys.

Comment: Use SUMPRODUCT instead (COUNTIF does not like arrays and must refer to a range):  `=SUMPRODUCT(--(WEEKDAY(SEQUENCE(EOMONTH(B3,0)-EOMONTH(B3,-1),,B3))=1))`